# Open new tab in bubblewrap'ed Firefox from outside the sandbox

Tags: linux, firefox, debian, bwrap

For security reasons I want to sandbox my browser and so I came up with the following wrapper script to run Firefox inside a bwrap sandbox:

```
$ cat ~/.local/bin/firefox
#!/bin/sh
MYDISPLAY="${DISPLAY##*:}"
MYDISPLAY="${MYDISPLAY%%.*}"
/usr/bin/bwrap \
    --unshare-all \
    --tmpfs /tmp \
    --bind ${HOME}/.cache/mozilla ${HOME}/.cache/mozilla \
    --bind ${HOME}/.mozilla ${HOME}/.mozilla \
    --bind ${HOME}/Downloads ${HOME}/Downloads \
    --bind /tmp/.X11-unix/X${MYDISPLAY} /tmp/.X11-unix/X${MYDISPLAY} \
    --ro-bind ${HOME}/.config/mimeapps.list ${HOME}/.config/mimeapps.list \
    --ro-bind ${HOME}/.local/share/fonts ${HOME}/.local/share/fonts \
    --ro-bind ${HOME}/.local/share/mime ${HOME}/.local/share/mime \
    --ro-bind /usr/bin /usr/bin \
    --ro-bind /usr/lib /usr/lib \
    --ro-bind /usr/lib64 /usr/lib64 \
    --ro-bind /usr/share /usr/share \
    --ro-bind /etc/alternatives /etc/alternatives \
    --ro-bind /etc/fonts /etc/fonts \
    --ro-bind /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf \
    --ro-bind /etc/ssl /etc/ssl \
    --ro-bind /etc/ca-certificates /etc/ca-certificates \
    --ro-bind ${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/pulse ${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/pulse \
    --symlink usr/bin /bin \
    --symlink usr/lib /lib \
    --symlink usr/lib64 /lib64 \
    --dev /dev \
    --dev-bind /dev/dri /dev/dri \
    --proc /proc \
    --setenv HOME ${HOME} \
    --hostname RESTRICTED \
    --share-net \
    --die-with-parent \
    --new-session \
    -- \
    /usr/bin/firefox "${@}"
```

This works pretty well. However, if Firefox is already running and I call e.g. `$ firefox "https://example.com"` I get the following error:

[image: Error message]

It is clear to me why this happens: bwrap creates a second sandbox and tries to start Firefox a second time inside the new sandbox.

What I want to achieve: Add a tab to the already running Firefox inside the first sandbox.

Therefore I would have to run the `$ firefox "https://example.com"` command somehow inside the already existing sandbox. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you try `firefox  --new-tab <url>`?

Comment: This does not work, because it spawns a new bwrap sandbox and throws the error message pictured at the screenshot.

Comment: Maybe a portable version of Firefox would work. There's a [Script on Github](https://gist.github.com/thewh1teagle/6a739c959b613f839eb3c5f9895a4505) to create it, but it's a bit beyond my knowledge. Maybe you can make something of it

Comment: @1NN: I had a look at the script you linked to, but I do not see how this could possibly solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the fact that there is an **official [Firefox flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/org.mozilla.firefox)** and Flatpak uses `bwrap` internally, there should be a way to get this to work.
Note that the easiest path would probably be to just use Firefox via that flatpak, and maybe tweak its configuration.

That being said, I was curious and dug into the implementation details:

- For security reasons, [`brwap` can only create new namespaces, but not enter existing ones](https://github.com/containers/bubblewrap/issues/253).
  The only way around this is to run some kind of job dispatcher in the sandbox that can receive the commands - which is basically what Firefox does, so let's see how that is implemented.
- The remoting mechanism for notifying an already running instance uses **DBus** when running on Linux *(see source code [here](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/remote/nsDBusRemoteClient.cpp#102) and [here](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/remote/nsRemoteService.cpp#145))*.
  The sandbox for the new `firefox` process must therefore be able to
  talk to the sandbox of the existing `firefox` process via DBus.
  The official Firefox flatpak therefore explicitly [grants access to the necessary DBus interfaces](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/taskcluster/docker/firefox-flatpak/runme.sh#l171).

  `brwap` by itself only allows passing through the DBus socket as a whole, which [is a security risk](https://github.com/containers/bubblewrap?tab=readme-ov-file#limitations).
  Flatpak solves this by giving the main DBus Unix socket to a new [xdg-dbus-proxy](https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-dbus-proxy/tree/main)
  instance (which is running in yet another sandbox) which exposes a "filtered" DBus Unix socket - the latter of which is then actually given to the application sandbox.

Based on the Firefox flatpak and me poking around the internals of flatpak, the invocation of `xdg-dbus-proxy` should look something like this:

```bash
xdg-dbus-proxy \
    unix:path=/var/run/user/$UID/bus \
    /run/user/$UID/.dbus-proxy/session-bus-proxy-$RANDOMID \
    --filter \
    --own="org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.firefox.*" \
    --own="org.mozilla.firefox.*" \
    --own="org.mozilla.firefox_beta.*"
```

A few notes:

1. Not tested yet.
2. `$RANDOMID` should be an alphanumeric string that is unique between different invocations of your firefox script.
3. The socket `/run/user/$UID/.dbus-proxy/session-bus-proxy-$RANDOMID` should be passed into your `bwrap` invocation using something like this:

   ```bash
   /usr/bin/bwrap ... \
     --ro-bind /run/user/$UID/.dbus-proxy/session-bus-proxy-$RANDOMID:/run/sandbox/bus \
     --setenv DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS unix:path=/run/sandbox/bus
   ```
4. The `flatpak` implementation does a bit more than that, like making sure that everything terminates together when the main process is closed.